# How do I use the PC 'delete' key when using VirtualBox on OS X, running Windows XP?

Tags: windows, macos, windows-xp, mac, virtualbox

How do I use the PC 'delete' key when using VirtualBox on OS X, running a Windows XP guest?

I tried every combination I could think of!

Comment: So you use a Mac keyboard? Which keyboard layout? Does `fn` + `backward delete` work for you?

Comment: It's the macbook pro keyboard (UK). I think that's done it actually, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On your Mac keyboard, try <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>backward delete</kbd> (<kbd>⌫</kbd>)

This would be the equivalent of a <kbd>forward delete</kbd> (<kbd>⌦</kbd>)

.. or just a "delete" on a Windows keyboard.